# Is there a way to move all applications from one monitor to another?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, fullscreen

Like many, I have an issue where when I plug my laptop back into my dock, all of my full screen applications are on different monitors than they were previously. They stay grouped somehow, but just switch which monitor they're on (so the apps on screen 1 are all now on screen 2, the apps on screen 2 are now all on screen 3, etc).

Is there a way to move *all* (or at least groups) of my applications to another screen instead of dragging each one-by-one?

Comment: Well, I thought the Display Preferences > Gather Windows would do the trick, but just tried it and it seems not.

Comment: Are all the apps in the same window?

Comment: No, it's multiple full screen applications on each monitor.